# Splice() return undefined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to return `colors(blue, yellow, red, grey)` into a sorts of rects, but idk why `splice()` always returns `undefined`. After printing some colors out, I need to solve this problem, otherwise the rect will never have a color.

```js
let randomColor = ["red", 'blue', 'yellow', 'grey']
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400)
  background(225)
  //generate four of the gathered four rect toward the horizon
  for (let t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
    //generate four of the gathered four rect toward vertical
    for (let w = 0; w < 2; w++) {
      //generate the gathered four rect toward the horizon
      for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        //generate the gathered four rect toward vertical
        for (let y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
          //generate the rect horizon
          for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            //generate the rect vertical
            for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
              let r = int(random(0, randomColor.length))
              console.log(randomColor[r])
              fill(randomColor[r])
              rect(((20 + 30 * i) + (65 * x)) + 140 * t, ((10 + 30 * j) + 65 * y) + 140 * w, 30, 30)
              randomColor.splice(r)
              rect(((20 + 30 * i) + (65 * x)) + 140 * t, ((10 + 30 * j) + 65 * y) + 140 * w, 30, 30)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your intention is to remove the element at `r`, use `randomColor.splice(r, 1)`, otherwise it will delete the element at r and all elements after r.  However, after doing this splice 4 times there will be nothing left in the array, which would seem to be bad in your case.

Comment: Well eventually you are going to be removing all of the elements from your array.... `randomColor = ["red", 'blue', 'yellow', 'grey'];
randomColor.splice(1);
console.log(randomColor)` simple demo show you what you are doing with the deleteCount not provided.